# Unexpected error calling ethereum contract using web3.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

Unexpected error calling ethereum contract using web3.js

```
MyContract.methods.actual_balance("0xE8D.........").call({})
.then(r=>{
    console.log(r)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

I'm getting error:

```
{ Error: Returned error: err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address 0x4..., maxFeePerGas: 3000000000 baseFee: 42784084648 (supplied gas 4700000)...
```

That is nonsense, I'm not sending transaction (send) but just querying state from local ledger. How is this posible?
Moreover, it was working an suddenly broke

geth version  1.10.8-stable-26675454

web3 version 1.5.3

full error msg:

```
 at Object.ErrorResponse (.../node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:36)
    at callback (.../node_modules/web3-providers-ipc/lib/index.js:56:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/web3-providers-ipc/lib/index.js:67:51)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:597:20) data: null }
```

Comment: Did you figure out why this was happening?

Answer (score 0):

web3 contract instance had gasPrice set very low. You can use https://ethgasstation.info/ to get actual price. I didn't knew that it does meters when you .call() not .send()